# LinkedIn Organization Share Statistics

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to retrieve share statistics in segments (by industry, by country, etc.).

It is **the default** in 'follower lifetime statistics' and 'page statistics'.

But in 'share statistics', even though its mentioned in the scheme:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity={organization URN}
```

retrieved only totalShareStatistics.

I can't find the correct path or other documentation.

Is it available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not available anymore. I got the following answer from the Linkedin technical support on their Zendesk about this issue.

> Apologies for the confusion. Those fields are actually no longer available in the API. We have a pending documentation change to remove those from that page.